# Python (3.5) - Formatting Number with Additional Text After

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is a fairly straight forward question, but I'm new so I'm having a hard time formatting this properly. I have some code that is downloading an item and providing me with a dynamic `print()` of the percentage complete.

```
while True:
    buf1 = resp.read(blocksize)
    if not buf1:
        break
    buf.write(buf1)
    size += len(buf1)
    if length:
        print('Downloading: {:.1f}\r%'.format(size/length*100), end='')# print('{:.2f}'.format(size/length), 'done')
print()
```

Let's take a closer look at that print line

`print('Downloading: {:.1f}\r%'.format(size/length*100), end='')`

Right now it's printing `%Downloading 100.0`

But I would like for it to print `Downloading 100.0%` (or maybe just without the decimal might look better)

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: What is the `\r` meant to do?  `\r` inserts a carriage return into the code which basically moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line... (and I'm also surpised at your reported output ... It seems like the `%` would be overwriting the `D`).

Comment: yeah stick `%` with `{:.1f}`.

Comment: So that the print doesn't duplicate itself, it's dynamic. So `100%` instead of `98%`, `99%` `100%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you want something like:

```
print('Downloading: {:.1f}%'.format(size/length*100), end='')
```

or possibly:

```
print('\rDownloading: {:.1f}%'.format(size/length*100), end='')
```

Basically, you're sticking a carriage return in the middle of the content that you want to keep together.  Your carriage return should be either before or after the content that you want to keep together.

Comment: Excellent, moving the `\r` to the front fixed it for me. It now reads `Downloading 100.0%` from 0 to 100 in the same statement (as opposed to multiple print lines). I'll accept answer in 5 min. Thanks again!